# How many grizzly bears did they spook in this sentence using “a couple of”？

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this sample sentence in Oxford Dictionary，under the entry "spook":

> They spooked a couple of grizzly bears.

I consulted an Oxford dictionary of English-Chinese edition, and it translates the sentence into  "They frightened two grizzly bears".

Maybe OK but I am still not fully convinced it means only two bears in the sentence. Does "a couple of bears" necessarily mean two, or have a meaning of more than two in most cases? As to in this sample sentence, I would prefer to interpret it as "they frightened some grizzly bears"(maybe they weren't quite sure of or didn't notice the exact number).

Help me.

Comment: It's true that *a couple of* could mean "an indefinite small number." However, I think it's fair to translate it as "two". That is my default understanding, unless the context indicates otherwise.

Comment: @DamkerngT. A grizzly bear couple? (Wait, I think this is what confused the OP.)

Comment: It suddenly occur to me that if "a couple" is used to refer certain people or things, it mostly tends to mean two; while used to refer words like "days","weeks","hours", it tends to mean 2 or 3, or even more than three. Agree?

Comment: I have to say its only two. What you are saying is more like "a few".

Comment: "a": 1, "a couple": 2, "a few": 3, "some": 4, "a handful": 5. Oftentimes these quantities also imply some room for error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grew up thinking that a *couple* meant *two*.

> They are a lovely *couple*.
>   A sense of hope *coupled* with a sense of loss...

When ordering two of something, it is no longer annoying to me (unlike when I first moved away from home) to be asked, "How many?"

The first and most important definition of *couple* is **two**.

> **Two items of the same kind**; a pair. (The American Heritage® Dictionary)(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)(many, many others)

A **couple of grizzly bears** is very unlikely to be *three*.

Synonyms: pair, two, brace, span (of horses or oxen), duo, twain (archaic), twosome *There are a couple of police officers standing guard.*

However, *informally*, it means a small number, usually **two** or **three**.

More than a couple is a *few*.

Answer (score 2):

*A couple of* is idiomatic (and less than formal) meaning *an indefinite small number, but at least two*. As you have noticed, some dictionaries will say this should be read as *two* exactly ([1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/couple)), but that does not reflect modern usage.

The assumption that it means *two* is because the idiom (*a couple of*) is etymologically related to, **but semantically distinct from**, the word *couple*, which means *exactly two items paired together*. You should read *a couple of* the same as *a few of* - more than one, but not very many (most likely not more than five).

Here are *a couple of* "modern" references: [1 (def. 14)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a+couple+of), [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/a+couple+of), [3 (def. 2)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-couple-of), [4](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/a-couple-of-more-minutes).

If you want to express that there were exactly two grizzly bears together, the most common turns of phrase are *a pair of grizzly bears* and *a grizzly bear couple*. Using a synonym or alternate construction ensures there's no ambiguity between the literal use of *couple* and the idiom *a couple of*.

Answer (score 0):

**A couple of** means more than two, but that doesn't imply it's too much. More than two, but not too many. But it may also mean two of them. I think from the context you have to judge what it should mean.

Here is a dictionary entry for the definition of **a couple of**

[image]

Example -

1. It will take a couple of days for the package to get there.
2. A dinner party, whether for a couple of old friends or eight new acquaintances, takes nearly the same amount of effort.

**Usage Note -**

> The phrase a couple of,  meaning “a small number of; a few; several,”
>   has been in standard use for centuries, especially with measurements
>   of time and distance and in referring to amounts of money: *They walked*
>   *a couple of miles in silence*. *Repairs will probably cost a couple of*
>   *hundred dollars*.  The phrase is used in all but the most formal speech
>   and writing.

**Source -**  The Random House Dictionary

Comment: So "a couple of" doesn't mean two according to this definition?

Comment: @dennylv I understand. But as I said you have to judge how many from the context. I have consulted a few dictionaries. Everywhere it says either two or more than two but not many.

Comment: Your answer makes me think that "a couple of something" *cannot* be "two" of that something. This is probably misleading.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Both "two" and "a few" is the possible substitute for "a couple of". That is what conclusion I drew from various dictionaries.

Comment: -1 - Everywhere it says *two* first.

Comment: Can't it be two grizzly bears, by using "a couple of" to suggest that they are a couple?

Comment: And I don't see any reason for down vote :)

Comment: It suddenly occur to me that if "a couple" is used to refer certain people or things, it mostly tends to mean two; while used to refer words like "days","weeks","hours", it tends to mean 2 or 3, or even more than three. Agree?

Comment: @dennylv Maybe archically, but not in modern English, precisely because of confusion with the idiom. We'd say *a pair of grizzly bears*, *a grizzly bear couple* or (not very likely) *a mated couple of grizzly bears* to convey exactly two bears paired together.

Comment: @Man_From_India I think what you concluded in your comment is fine; however, your answer still makes me read it differently. I don't have the Random House Dictionary, but I searched for the text in your usage note and found [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/couple). In sense 14, it says "more than two ...; a small number of; a few; [examples...]". Compare to what you wrote: couple of means "more than two, but ...; More than two, but ...; But it may also mean two of them." -- To sum it up, I read it as "three or more (but ...); three or more (but ...); but maybe two".

Comment: @dennylv: That people/timespans distinction isn't to do with the word ***couple*** itself - it's just that we're more likely to be using the more "vague" form *(couple = a few, most likely 2 or 3 but probably no more than 4)* with timespans. But I could reasonably say *"I felt a bit awkward at the party because I only really knew a couple of people there"* even if I actually knew 4 (or feasibly even *more*) people.